# Advanced configuration with the golang Viper lib

Tags: go, yaml, config

I'm working on my first real Go project and have been searching for some tools to handle the configuration.

Finally, I've found this tool: [**https://github.com/spf13/viper**](https://github.com/spf13/viper) which is really nice but I have some issues when I try to handle some more complex configurations such as the following config.yaml example:

```
app:
  name: "project-name"
  version 1

models:
  modelA:
    varA: "foo"
    varB: "bar"

  modelB:
    varA: "baz"
    varB: "qux"
    varC: "norf"
```

I don't know how to get the values from modelB for example. While looking at the lib code, I've found the followings but I don't really understand how to use it:

```
// Marshals the config into a Struct
func Marshal(rawVal interface{}) error {...}

func AllSettings() map[string]interface{} {...}
```

What I want is to be able, from everywhere in my package, to do something like:

```
modelsConf := viper.Get("models")
fmt.Println(modelsConf["modelA"]["varA"])
```

Could someone explain me the best way to achieve this?

Comment: It all depends if your data is consistent. If all models only contain varA and varB, why would you make a new entity called modelA (and modelB)? But if modelB contains varA, varB and varC, then you must make something completely different.

Comment: In fact, modelB should also be able to contain a varC, I've updated the example in my initial question

Comment: Take a look at this [link](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#example_RawMessage)

Comment: Ok, I get your point as this link is pretty clear on how to do what I want to do. Sadly, I think that I'll have to go for a homemade solution instead of using Viper. Anyway, thanks for your help. If anyone else knows a solution to do this with Viper, you are welcome :)!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since the "models" block is a map, it's a bit easier to call

```
m := viper.GetStringMap("models")
```

m will be a map[string]interface {}

Then, you get the value of m[key], which is an interface {}, so you cast it to map[interface {}]interface {} :

```
m := v.GetStringMap("models")
mm := m["modelA"].(map[interface{}]interface{})
```

Now you can access "varA" key passing the key as an interface {} :

```
mmm := mm[string("varA")]
```

mmm is foo

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use:

`m := viper.Get("models.modelA")`

or

`newViperForModelA := viper.Sub("models").Sub("modelA")`